# How do I get the week number by starting as 1 from a specific date of the year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

Been trying out quite a lot of samples posted in the forum but to no avail.  The week number given is per calendar year.  How do I go about getting week number like this:

Start Date: 1st Mar 2021 (Week number starts at 1 based on input start date)

```
Subsequent Date     | Week Number
--------------------|------------
1 - 7 Mar 2021      | 1
8 - 14 Mar 2021     | 2
15 - 21 Mar 2021    | 3
21 - 28 Mar 2021    | 4
29 Mar - 2 Apr 2021 | 5
.
.
.
.
```

Week start on a Monday.  Week Number is running up till end of fiscal year, i.e. end of Feb.  It is reset to 1 at every March.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: i'm using SQL Server

Comment: Hi Matt! There are numerous different week numbering systems (e.g. some have an extended week 52, some have a [partial] week 53, some start on a Monday, some Sunday, etc.). Based on your example we could assume your week number scheme starts on the 1st of January each year and counts up to 53, resetting to 1 again on January 1st. **Is this correct?** If so, please update your question to include this information.

Comment: Seems like what you need to do is create a calendar table in your instance; then you can get the week number for any date, as it's in your calendar table.

Comment: You can calculate the week by datediff/7 basing on January 1st of the corresponding year... furthermore the DATEPART(ww) gives the calendar week, but this might differ from the expected result as you described it. See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99439/8/2

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the dates and divide by 7.  Naively, this would be:

```
1 + datediff( day, datefromparts(year(datecol), 3, 1), datecol ) / 7
```

This doesn't work for January and February.  So we can use a little trick of subtracting 2 months from the date for the year:

```
1 + (datediff( day,
               datefromparts(year(dateadd(month, -2, datecol)), 3, 1),
               datecol
             ) / 7)
```